# How do I gain access to number_with_presicion using a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Inside my ruby script I would like to use, `number_with_presicion`. How would I go about this? `Include *something*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you script file

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

now you can use -> `new_number = (number_with_precision 3556.22321, :precision => 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
irb --> require 'action_view'
    ==> true

irb --> ActionView::Base.new.number_with_precision 1234
    ==> "1234.000"
```

You need to require `action_view` in your ruby script.

**UPDATE**

To be able to use `number_with_precision` without typing `ActionView::Base`, you need to extend `Numeric` class like this

```
require 'action_view'
class Numeric
  def number_with_precision
    ActionView::Base.new.number_with_precision(self)
  end
end
```

After this, you can use it like this

```
irb --> 10.number_with_precision
==> "10.000"
```

Obviously, you can put this extension in a file and require that file via `require` and you'll have the extension available in your Ruby script.

Comment: can I use this without typing ActionView::Base ?